# Blur background with Nikon Coolpix B700

Tags: photography-basics

I am not professional photographer and own a Nikon Coolpix B700.

I am trying to achieve background blur aka bokeh with my clicks with same camera. I have done google and played around Manual setting as suggested yet I am unable to achieve that. People have accomplished this with same camera. Only difference I observed is uses of tripod. Do I must have tripod to have bokeh with B700? Can't I have such without uses of tripod? Suggestion please!

I am keen to learn basic of photography jargon and how to use it with B700. Would be great if someone can suggest a tutorial or guide.

Thanks

Comment: Also [How to maximize the blurred background look with a distant subject?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100220/75526)

Answer (score 1):

A camera such as yours has more Depth of Field than a DSLR. To obtain background blur:

1. Use aperture priority mode and use the widest aperture (smallest f-number)
2. use the long focals (ie, zoom a lot)
3. have the maximum distance difference between subject and background (in other words try to get close to the subject, and keep the subject far from its background).

Comment: Thanks. I will try again and update. As I mentioned in original post, I tried based on suggestion on internet but couldn't do it. Whoever had shown, had tripod. Do I need tripod one?

Comment: No, a tripod isn't needed, if the image stabilization of yoru camera is sufficient.

Comment: Don't points 2 and 3 contradict each other?

Comment: No, you can use a background far, far, away :) As in all things in photography, a matter of compromise. Of course, if this was easy to achieve, the question wouldn't even have been asked.

Comment: Effect on background blur: focal length > distance ratios > aperture. So zoom in as much as you can, get as close to the subject as you can, and open up the aperture as much as you can, in that order. You will get more blur by zooming in more, even if you have to back up a bit. Don't worry too much if the aperture ends up closer to F8 than to F1.